# ADFS Client AquireToken Error

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, adfs3.0

I'm creating a WebAPI that needs to authenticate against ADFS.
I am [this lab](http://www.timecockpit.com/devblog/2015/02/02/ADFS-and-ADAL-Lab) but I keep running into a problem when I try have a client connect to it. I have setup the Web API on a test server and have provisioned a ADFS Client but every time I try to connect using a client I keep getting the following error window when the code runs the

[image]

This happens every time the following code is hit

```
AuthenticationResult ar = ac.AcquireToken(resourceURI, clientID, new Uri(returnURI));
```

I have no idea where or what is causing this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Event viewer in the box running ADFS (Window key-R: eventvwr.msc), and check the ADFS event log.
[image]

It should contain information about the error you are seeing. You can also enable debug logs. Right click the Admin node, select View and click 'Show Analytic and Debug logs'. Then open the 'AD FS Tracing' node, right click the Debug node and select 'Enable log'.

HTH